# Debugging eclipse crashes

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I installed `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
This combination is very unstable, it seems. By unstable I mean that it crashes at random times.

How do I enable debug logging in eclipse?

I start eclipse with the following options in eclipse.ini:

`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
-XX:MaxPermSize=768M
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-debug`

It looks like eclipse crashes without writing a crash logfile. I would love to know why it crashes.

Adding `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` to config made it more stable but it still crashes at random times.

Comment: Back off an android version or two until you have a stable configuration.

Comment: I can always do that. But I would love to know how to get some log to stdout so that I can at least see what happens when eclipse crashes - there is no stacktrace or anything, it as if someone calls exit() or something.